# What will be the antipode of a given point (latitude, longitude) = (2x, y) on a sphere? How to calculate this?

Tags: geometry

I want to calculate the antipodal point of a given point on a sphere. The point is described with the value of latitude and longitude. The point has latitude of 2x and longitude of y. What will be the antipodal point of this point? How to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antipodal point has coordinates

```
(-2x, y>0? y-180: y+180)
```